# Dynamic Routing (Auto Create Route) on Laravel 5 - View not rendered on App::call()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Basically, I have an admin (CMS) for my app. I have included menu and submenu setup, which are eventually populated on my nav section.

```
Name: User
URL: setup/user
Icon: fa fa-user
```

The problem is, if I add new menu (like above), I have to setup another route on web.php, like:

```
Route::resource('setup/user','UserController');
```

Well, there will be lots of menu to be created and my web.php is somehow messed up with lots of routes.

I followed this article and it gave me an idea, I tweaked it and created my own.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamically-calling-a-controller-method-in-laravel-5

Here's what I've done:

```
function wildcard($route, $controller, $verbs = ['get', 'post']) {

$stack      = Route::getGroupStack();
$namespace  = end($stack)['namespace'];
$controller = ucfirst(strtolower($route)).'Controller';


Route::match($verbs, rtrim($route, '/') . '/{method}', function($method, $params = null) use ($route, $namespace, $controller)
{

    $controller = $namespace . '\\' . $controller;

    $method = $controller . '@' . $method;
    $params
        ? App::call($method, explode('/', $params))
        : App::call($method);

});
}

wildcard('home',null);
```

My HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('pages.common.dashboard');
}
```

But it doesn't display the view on my index method, just blank page. But it did get the method because I can dump from the method.

Maybe there's a better way on dynamic routing. Thanks.

Comment: I had ran into the exact same situation, does anybody have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** You must `return` your `App::call()`

```
Route::match($verbs, rtrim($route, '/') . '/{method}', function($method, $params = null) use ($route, $namespace, $controller)
{

    $controller = $namespace . '\\' . $controller;

    $method = $controller . '@' . $method;
    if($params){
            // return the App::call
            return App::call($method, explode('/', $params));
    } else {
            // return the App::call
            return App::call($method);
    }
});
```